# I want to add jstl C:if tag in my code in a form but not able to understand how to implement it

Tags: forms, jsp, jstl

```
Hello i want to add JSTL C:if tag in a form but did not able to understand how to implement it .
i have a file for attractions where i want to add the c:if tag in it the task i want to carry out is whenever i am navigating from other page to this present page if there are no datas available from database it should show " no datas available please add new data "
 the code for for the form is as follows
```

this is the code where i have to add the c:if tag it explains as this shows the list of attractions with its id's from the database that is navigated from city page in sort i want the output as if i navigate from city to attraction page and if there are no attractions in it i should get the message as " no datas available please add new data "

```
<div class="row">
            <div id="attractionList" class="col-sm-12">
                <h3 >
                    Attractions
                </h3>


                <c:forEach items="${attraction}" var="a">

                    <div id="attractionTable" class="col-sm-3">
                        <form action="/RouternData/roternInternal" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" value="YES" name="DELETEATTRACTION">
                                <input type="hidden" value="${a.cityid }" name="cityid">


                            <div class="box7">
                                <div>
                                <img alt="image1" src="jspfiles/image/vadodara-palace1.jpg"
                                        width="100%" height="100px">

                                </div>
                                <div>



                                    <br> <a
                                        href='/RouternData/roternInternal?RETRIVEATTRACTIONDATA=YES&attractionId=${a.attractionId}'
                                        onclick ="showAttractions()" name="attractionname">${a.attraction }</a><br>


                                    <b>Day ;</b> <i> ${a.days }</i><br>
                                     <b>Type of attraction :</b> <i>${a.type}</i><br>

                                     <button type="submit" style="color: #990000" class="btn btn-link" value="${a.attractionId}"
                                            name="attractionId">Delete</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <%-- <h3>${a.attraction }</h3>--%>


                </c:forEach>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [JSTL1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

```
length( java.lang.Object)
```

returns the number of items in a collection, or the number of characters in a string.

Apply following code at the beginning of your page in order to use `fn` namespace

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Assuming `${attraction}` is a `Java Collection` object, you may use `c:choose` to decide what to do if `${attraction}` is empty or not

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(attraction) gt 0}">
        <!-- attraction is not empty -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <!-- attraction is empty -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```